# How to write a neuroscience research abstract?

Tags: neuroscience

I might have to start working on a research abstract for college soon, and I am looking for basic tips on beginning one. I don't mean information about the research specifically; I simply mean information in regard to how to do the writing.

Comment: Be persistent, don't let yourself be distracted, compare with other abstracts. Maybe [this also helps](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/essays/abstract.html)